# "Extending" anonymous class after instance creation

Tags: java, design-patterns, anonymous-class

Suppose I have to assign event handlers for events that occur during a `Request`. The API exposes an abstract class `RequestHandlerAPIAdapter` and an interface `RequestHandlerAPI` to manually define event handlers. `RequestHandlerAPIAdapter` implements `RequestHandlerAPI`. The adapter only exists so I can do the following:

```
client.setRequestHandler(new RequestHandlerAPIAdapter(Request request) {
    // override some or all inherited methods
});
```

Note that the adapter is allowing me to handle only the events I'm interested in and leave out others. For example, if I just want to do certain things when a request is sent and don't care what happens when it is being processed or response has arrived, I can only specify a handler for `onRequestSent` and leave out `onRequestProcessing` and `onResponseArrived`. This design pattern suffices most real world needs.

Now suppose that I don't know what events I need to handle beforehand and I might decide whether or not `onResponseArrived` should be handled manually in the future, after creating the anonymous instance of `RequestHandlerAPIAdapter`. A new instance of `RequestHandlerAPIAdapter` will be required and I'll have to repeat the definition of `onRequestSent`. I know this sounds bizarre and perhaps developers never need  to write code this way, but I want to know if there is a workaround to prevent code repetition in this case.

One solution that I came up with is to create a concrete class that implements `RequestHandlerAPI` or extends `RequestHandlerAPIAdapter`, defines public functional interfaces for every inherited method, defines private fields for all the functional interfaces just defined and add a method `setHandler` for every event that may occur during the request.

Here's the code for such a class:

```
public class RequestHandlerConcreteAdapter implements RequestHandlerAPI {
    private HandleOnRequestSent onRequestSent = null; // or may be an empty lambda expression that does nothing
    private HandleOnRequestProcessing onRequestProcessing = null;
    private HandleOnResponseRetrieved onResonseRetrieved = null;

    public interface HandleOnRequestSent {
        void onRequestSent (Request request);
    }

    public interface HandleOnRequestProcessing {
        void onRequestProcessing (Request request);
    }

    public interface HandleOnResponseRetrived {
        void onResponseRetrived (Request request, Response response);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestSent (Request request) {
        onRequestSent.onRequestSent(request);
    }

    public RequestHandlerConcreteAdapter setHandler (HanldeOnRequestSent h) {
        onRequestSent = h;
        return this; // allows us to chain methods
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestProcessing (Request request) {
        onRequestProcessing.onrequestProcessing(request);
    }

    // overloaded
    public RequestHandlerConcreteAdapter setHandler (HanldeOnRequestProcessing h) {
        onRequestProcessing = h;
        return this; // allows us to chain methods
    }

    // and a pair to handle onResponseRetrived
}
```

This allows me to do something like this:

```
RequestHandlerConcreteAdapter adapter = new RequestHandlerConcreteAdapter ();

adapter.setHandler ( (RequestHandlerConcreteAdapter.HandleOnRequestSent) (request) -> {
    //do something here
});

client.setRequestHandler (adapter);

// and at a later time
adapter.setHandler ( (RequestHandlerConcreteAdapter.HanldeOnResponseRetrieved) (request, response) -> {
    // do something here
});

client.setRequestHandler (adapter);
```

I would look for every possibility to avoid doing what I did above because this solution looks so dirty to me. Also, I would like to know if what I did is a known design pattern in Java.

To sum up, I want to know if there's a cleaner way to achieve what the code above is doing and if not, can you suggest some improvements on the code so it looks a bit less dirty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you're simply looking for the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). Implement a `RequestHandlerAPIDecorator` which is created with an instance of `RequestHandlerAPI` and delegates all `onRequest<DoSomething>` calls to it. To override certain operation, subclass the `RequestHandlerAPIDecorator` and override one of the methods.

Something along the lines:

```
 public abstract class RequestHandlerAPIDecorator implements RequestHandlerAPI {

     protected final RequestHandlerAPI delegate;

     public RequestHandlerAPIDecorator(RequestHandlerAPI delegate) {
         this.delegate = Objects.requireNonNull(delegate, "delegate must not be null.");
     }

     public void onRequestProcessing(Request request) {
         delegate.onRequestProcessing(request);
     }

     // Etc. You IDE will happily generate delegate methods for you.
 }
```

Now if you want to override, say "request sent" handling for some existing `RequestHandlerAPI`, you simply do:

```
 RequestHandlerAPI decoratedRequestHandler = 
     new RequestHandlerAPIDecorator(existingRequestHandler) {
         public void onRequestSent(Request request) {
             System.out.println("Request is sent.");
         }
     });
```

You can either implement handling from the scratch or do something additionally, calling `delegate.onRequestSent(request)` afterwards.

Comment: How to create the `existingRequestHandler`? We don't have any instance of `RequestHandlerAPI` at the beginning.

Comment: @DevashishJaiswal Isn't your stated objective to extend an instance of anonymous class after creation? So `existingRequestHandler` is the instance of anonymous class you want to extend.

Comment: oh, you're right :) I missed this clarity in my solution. Thanks!